# Insert into multiple tables form one query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am retrieving the `SUM` of some data from a query. The `SUM` can have both negative and positive values. I want to insert the positive values to one table and the negative values to another table.

The result set for the select query is like below

```
total       |   userid
-----------------------
4750.00     |   11
1339.00     |   3607
-681.81     |   3600
```

I was planning to insert the details from the select query directly to the table, `INSERT into table (amount,user) SELECT SUM(..) AS total,userid FROM...` . But I was not able to figure out how to do it in a single query.

I am using `PostgreSQL 8.4.17`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do it in two queries?

Comment: There is no issue in using two queries. But still i don't get how to add an `if/else` statement in between the `INSERT` and `SELECT`query

Answer (score 2):

Use the `where` statement in two separate `inserts`:

```
INSERT into positives (amount,user)
    SELECT SUM(..) AS total, userid
    FROM...
    having sum(..) > 0;

INSERT into negatives (amount,user)
    SELECT SUM(..) AS total, userid
    FROM...
    having sum(..) < 0;
```

Comment: The equation inside the sum is a complex one `SUM( ((a*b)/100) - (c/100) )`. So calculating it two times can be a bit heavy ... right?

Comment: @NandakumarV . . . That is not really that complicated.  The bigger performance hit is reading the table twice.  If the query really takes a noticeable amount of time to run, then put the full results in a temporary table and just insert from that.